# How to make stored procedure change return value on SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to change what the stored procedure returns without altering data. I'm trying to have it return 1 every time LinkItemType = 3, but I keep getting syntax error. Please help.

Here is what I have.

```
DECLARE @ITEMTYPE Int

SELECT TOP 1000 
    [DataID]
    ,[ContactServiceID]
    ,[LinkID]
    ,@ITEMTYPE
    WHEN [LinkItemType] = 3 THEN @ITEMTYPE = 1 ELSE @ITEMTYPE = [LinkItemType]
FROM 
    [BCM2010].[dbo].[EntityReferences]
WHERE
    dataid = 54
ORDER BY 
    LinkItemType DESC
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned which brand of SQL, but try `Case When [LinkItemType] = 3 Then 1 Else [LinkItemType] End`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Laurence said is correct. What you are looking for is likely:

*(note, I am not using your variable)*

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [DataID]
  ,[ContactServiceID]
  ,[LinkID]
  ,ITEMTYPE = CASE WHEN [LinkItemType] = 3 THEN 1 ELSE [LinkItemType] END
 FROM [BCM2010].[dbo].[EntityReferences]
 WHERE dataid = 54
 ORDER BY ITEMTYPE DESC
```

Comment: I tried that but for some reason the records where LinkItemType = 3 stopped beeing selected.